# Failed to pass intent to another class

Tags: android

follow up to the code and can not find where the application goes down, I realized that the data reaches the ListCat.java class, but falls

My class extends the fragment

```
05-13 20:26:00.777  12398-12398/com.learn2crack.tab E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.learn2crack.tab, PID: 12398
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.learn2crack.tab/com.learn2crack.tab.ListaCat}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2209)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2269)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:139)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1210)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5102)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
            at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.main(XposedBridge.java:133)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'
            at android.app.ListActivity.onContentChanged(ListActivity.java:243)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:293)
            at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1937)
            at com.learn2crack.tab.ListaCat.onCreate(ListaCat.java:17)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5248)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1110)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2173)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2269)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:139)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1210)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5102)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
            at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.main(XposedBridge.java:133)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

class Categoria.java

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        final View categoria = inflater.inflate(R.layout.android_frag, container, false);

final ListView  lv = (ListView) categoria.findViewById(R.id.list);
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {


    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                            int position, long id) {
        // getting values from selected ListItem

        TextView txt = (TextView) parent.getChildAt(position - lv.getFirstVisiblePosition()).findViewById(R.id.idCAT);
        String tagId = txt.getText().toString();


        // Starting single contact activity
        Intent in = new Intent(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),ListaCat.class);
        in.putExtra(TAG_ID, tagId);
        startActivity(in);
```

List_item.xml

```
<LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="name"
            android:id="@+id/name"
            android:textColor="#ff7900"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:gravity="fill_horizontal" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/idCAT"
            android:visibility="visible" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

android_frag.xml

```
<ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/list" />
```

Comment: Where's your `ListaCat`'s `onCreate()`? Did you forgot the setContentView and/or are setting the wrong one?

Comment: ListCat.java `setContentView(R.layout.listalocales);`

Comment: That's your problem then. What's in `listalocales`? (please edit your question). You've only shown that the `list` is in `android_frag.xml`, and... well, you don't seem to be using that.

Comment: I have 2 that I need to take data from list_item.xml in @ id/name and @ id/id

Comment: post your listalocales.xml to your question. It seems you're using a ListFragment, but have the hosting activity declared as a ListActivity. That breaks.

Comment: @323go ready, exactly LISTCAT was widespread ListActivity, activity and change it to run it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are using `ListActivity`, but do not define a `ListView` in the layout file with the id `@android:id/list`. Either do that or use a normal `Activity`. More about `ListActivity` [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListActivity.html).

Comment: edit the content above,I have in my android_frag.xml my id / list

Comment: Another query, add a ListAdapter now, I have to change it to extends ListActivity?

Answer (score 0):

your principal Error is

```
 Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'
```

Quit `getActivity().getApplicationContext()`

```
Intent in = new Intent(getActivity(),ListaCat.class);
in.putExtra(TAG_ID, tagId);
startActivity(in);
```

Check if your List is `android.R.id.list` in

```
(ListView) categoria.findViewById(R.id.list);
```

You need import your R.java from your project not from android.R